# Swift 3 - Working with UnsafePointer<CFDictionary>?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, core-audio

I'm currently reading Chris Adamson's "Learning Core Audio" and try to follow along in **Swift 3** (instead of **Objective-C**).

The first code example makes use of `AudioTool` to gather information about an audio-file. My Swift 3 version looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import AudioToolbox

func main() {
    let arguments = CommandLine.arguments

    guard arguments.count > 1 else {
        print("Usage: CAMetaData /full/path/to/audiofile")
        return
    }

    // Get filepath out of cmd-arguments
    let audiofilePath = NSString(string: arguments[1]).expandingTildeInPath

    // Load audio file into appropriate data structure
    let audioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audiofilePath)
    var audiofile: AudioFileID? = nil
    var possibleError = noErr

    possibleError = AudioFileOpenURL(audioURL, AudioFilePermissions.readPermission, 0, &audiofile)
    assert(possibleError == noErr)

    // Get size of metadata dictionary
    var outDataSize: UInt32 = 0

    possibleError = AudioFileGetPropertyInfo(audiofile!, kAudioFilePropertyInfoDictionary, &outDataSize, nil)
    assert(possibleError == noErr)

    // Get metadata
    var outDataPointer: UnsafePointer<CFDictionary>? = nil

    possibleError = AudioFileGetProperty(audiofile!, kAudioFilePropertyInfoDictionary, &outDataSize, &outDataPointer)
    assert(possibleError == noErr)

    // How to use this outDataPointer?
    let outData = outDataPointer!.pointee as NSDictionary
    dump(outData)

    // No CFRelease necessary - Swift takes care of that

    // Close connection to audiofile
    possibleError = AudioFileClose(audiofile!)
    assert(possibleError == noErr)
}

main()
```

Everything seems to work great (all assertions/`AudioToolbox`-API call pass). Now I'm asking myself how I'm able to display the data stored inside the `outDataPointer`.

This is how I understand the situation: `outDataPointer` holds an optional with associated type `UnsafePointer<CFDictionary>`. I'm able to verify that `outDataPointer` is not `nil`, therefore accessing the associated value won't crash my program. `outDataPointer!.pointee` should give me the `CFDictionary` pointed to by the associated value behind `outDataPointer`. `CFDictionary` is castable to `NSDictionary`.

Sadly dumping the underlaying data prints

> - __NSAtom #0

to the console. Quite not what I expected (information about the audiofile). How can I get this data out of my `outDataPointer` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift's `CFDictionary` isn't itself a data structure; it's a pointer to a data structure, and it is equivalent to Objective-C's `CFDictionaryRef`.  In other words, it behaves like a Swift `class`, not a `struct`.

The value written into `outDataPointer` is not a pointer to a `CFDictionary`; it *is* a `CFDictionary`.  You're dereferencing it one too many times, causing the data stored in the dictionary to be treated as a pointer to a dictionary.  On my system, the resulting memory address was `0x001dffffc892e2f1`, which Objective-C treats as a [tagged pointer](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html), resulting in the `NSAtom` message.

To fix the problem, declare `outDataPointer` as a `CFDictionary?` instead of an `UnsafePointer<CFDictionary>?`:

```
// Get metadata
var outDataPointer: CFDictionary? = nil

possibleError = AudioFileGetProperty(audiofile!, kAudioFilePropertyInfoDictionary, &outDataSize, &outDataPointer)
assert(possibleError == noErr)

let outData = outDataPointer! as NSDictionary
dump(outData)
```

Output:

```
▿ 1 key/value pair #0
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - .0: approximate duration in seconds #1
      - super: __NSCFString
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
    - .1: 187.387 #2
      - super: NSString
        - super: NSObject
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! This definitely cleared things up for me. I'm not even sure how I ended up using `UnsafePointer<CFDictionary>` in the first place. Everything is working as expected now.

Comment: @NobodyNada, what is the reason of using `CFDictionary` if we can use `NSDictionary` right in the `AudioFileGetProperty`? And is there a way to use Swift Dictionary? (I tried [String:Any] and it wasn't filled with key/values...) Thanks